# Laravel 5.3 Completely replace default auth by Cartalyst/Sentinel

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, cartalyst-sentinel

I have fresh project on Laravel 5.3 and I want to user Cartalyst/Sentinel as default auth and roles manager.
I tried to find some documentation about - how to make Sentinel default Auth manager, but don't find any enough accurate answers.
Could someone provide with step-by-step instruction - what and where need to be changed, replaced, added to use Sentinel in right way?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation of both the sites have instructions for this :

1) Laravel - https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#adding-custom-guards and https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers

2) Sentinel - https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0#laravel-5

Follow what Sentinel guys have to say for now. Understanding how Laravel manages to allow custom Auth system will help you as well.